# How to select the threshold parameter using Cross-validation?

Tags: cross-validation

I was reading the article "Canonical thresholding for non-sparse high-dimensional linear regression" (It's available here: "https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.12313"), In the discussion about the choice of the threshold parameter they suggest that they can use Cross-validation, I know how to do it for the tuning parameter of Lasso in R  for example but here I am a little bit confused, could any one of explain how to that?

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! Thanks for the ArXiv link. Could you please say a bit about what kind of threshold you are trying to optimize? We like questions here to be as self-contained as possible.

Comment: Thanks, Dave, In fact, One of the famous ways to reduce dimension for a model Y= BX + E  is the PCA to get a model Y= θZ + E, where Z=QX where  Q is a matrix of the principal component, then estimate the parameter coefficient θ. We can go back to the estimation of B in high dimension by transforming B= t(Q)%*%θ . The canonical thresholding proposes to threshold the parameter before going back to a high dimension function that is B= t(Q)%*% soft(θ), soft is a threshold function defined by soft(z)= z  max (1-\tau /|z|, 0)$. So  how to select the optimum threshold parameter \tau by Cross-valid.